# Is there a way to use findElements and limit the results to the first x items

Tags: java, selenium

I have a table which can vary greatly in the number of columns it contains (20 columns up to 10,000).  I have a method which gets the table data so that I can compare the data values, but I generally only need values which occur in the first few columns.  To get the column data from a row I am using:

```
List<WebElement> columns = rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

This gets the columns (td elements) for row number rnum in the table.

My question is: is there a way to limit findElements to return only the first xx number of results?  maybe return only the first 100 columns?  The method works great when there are 20 columns, but takes forever when there are 10000 columns.  Or, is there a better way to iterate the row data's TD elements so that I can break from the loop when I've found the column that I want?

Answer (score 2):

You can first reach the 20th element using the index and then you can use `preceding` in the xpath to fetch all the elements before that element. It would give you the first 19 elements in that case.

You can do it like:

```
List<WebElement> columns = rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.xpath("//td[20]//preceding::td"));
```

You can fetch any number of elements by using this, you just need to mention that value in the xpath as the index.

Comment: I should have explained better, but not all of the rows have the same number of columns (I have embedded tables).  I am not sure that td[20] will necessarily exist.  However, if I know that I need column 20 and it does not exist on that row, then I can skip the row.  I will try this!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have `n` columns from below list

```
List<WebElement> columns = rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

and you want to access only first 50 columns. You can achieve in two ways in Java.

**Solution-1: We can use subList function to get first 50 elements**

```
 List<WebElement> firstFiftyCols = columns.subList(0, 50);
```

**Solution-2: Using Java 8 Streams**

```
List<WebElement> firstFiftyCols = columns.stream().limit(50).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Solution-3: Select first `N` node with help of `xpath`**

```
List<WebElement> firstFiftyCols = rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.xpath("/td[position() >= 1 and not(position() > 50)]"));
```

**Note :I have tried this xpath and check if columns are less than 50 then it return list till last column.**

Replace 50 to the number of columns you want to access.

Comment: @DebanjanB  Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, this will still get the entire list of columns in the row, which is what I need to avoid because it takes so long to process.  However, the subList and stream both look to be a very useful way to return just the first xx columns!